# How to add dictionary to array

Tags: vbscript

Simple example:

```
Dim d, a(0)
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.Add "a", "Athens"
d.Add "b", "Belgrade"
d.Add "c", "Cairo"
Set a(0) = d

WScript.Echo(TypeName(a))
```

Output:

`Variant()`

I don't see any way how to access this object, it counts 3, but it seems like empty

I find it surprising that Google does not list any useful result for this question - how to assign dictionary in array?

Closest I found was this unanswered [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1397563)

My problem is that I have a loop that creates temporary dictionary, which I planned to feed in simple one dimensional array with dictionary objects, but without success

I also found something like this [link](http://wiki.mcneel.com/developer/scriptsamples/dictionary) where two arrays are created for dictionary keys and for dictionary items (values) separately, which just complicated things too much for my case

So is this possible at all with VBScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might have misunderstood your question, but you can access the Dictionary like this:

```
WScript.Echo(a(0).Item("b"))
```

*Edit*

This code:

```
Dim d, a(0)
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.Add "a", "Athens"
d.Add "b", "Belgrade"
d.Add "c", "Cairo"
Set a(0) = d
WScript.Echo(a(0).Item("b"))

dim x
x = d.Items

dim i
for i = lbound(x) to ubound(x)
    WScript.Echo(x(i))
next
```

Produces this output on my Windows 7 machine:

```
C:\>cscript test.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Belgrade
Athens
Belgrade
Cairo

C:\>
```

Comment: Just like I wanted, but unfortunately it throws an error: `Type mismatch`

Comment: I've added a complete example that includes version numbers, what version of vbscript are you using?

Comment: Sorry, it was typo at my end (my dict was `d` and I just pasted your answer) It works perfectly, thanks

Comment: What helped me was the "set" command, i was doing a(0) = d but when I switched it to set a(0) = d, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

An example :

```
Dim d
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 
d.Add "a", "Athens" 
d.Add "b", "Belgrade" 
d.Add "c", "Cairo" 

WScript.Echo(d("a")) '=> Athens

d("a") = "Brussels"

WScript.Echo(d("a")) '=> Brussels

a = d.Keys   ' Get the keys.
b = d.Items
For i = 0 To d.Count -1 ' Iterate the array.
  wscript.echo a(i) & " " & b(i)
Next


'=>a Brussels
'=>b Belgrade
'=>c Cairo
```

Comment: Yes, but dividing keys/items in separate arrays complicates a bit when using loop and dict has variable keys. In simple example it's clear of course. Thanks guys, I found the problem I had with your answers - if looping over temp dict and assigning it to array, dict has to be destroyed after adding it to array and Dictionary object recreated again. I was using `dict.RemoveAll` instead, and got into this trouble. Cheers